# May I re-ask my closed question, and answer it myself?

Tags: support, questions, closed-questions, asking-questions

Is it OK to re-ask question which has been [closed for not being real question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669281/efficient-way-to-compare-sublists-across-lists-of-lists), if it's formed properly this time? (I'd prefer it over editing the original question, which might create confusion, because it would alter the meaning of existing posts and comments.)
If it is, is it OK to answer your own question then, and also let others to provide answer if they think it's in any way better than my own?
If yes, should I write few words about the context(with link to original question, and this question here on meta), or simply post answer and question?
Thanks for help.

Comment: So long as your new question is sufficiently a "real question," it will also be different enough to remain open. If you're really just asking the same question, though, you should expect it to be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it OK to re-ask question which has been closed for not being real question

No.  You shouldn't re-ask a question of yours that has been closed.  You should be editing the question and, if the community feels that the question is appropriate after your edits, it can be reopened.  After all, questions are closed specifically to provide an opportunity for the question to be improved.

Comments that are obsolete as a result of edits to the question can be cleaned up by a mod; just flag them as "obsolete".  If there's a lot just flag one under "other" and inform the mod that a lot of the comments are no longer applicable and should be removed; they will be able to look over the question and perform the appropriate cleanup.

You should only post a new question if it really is a completely different question.

> If it is, is it OK to answer your own question then, and also let others to provide answer if they think it's in any way better than my own?

Yes, you can self answer a question if you want.  I'll warn you though, doing this is *hard*.  In particular, it's quite difficult to write a high quality question when you already know the answer.  You're *allowed* to, but very few people tend to do this well, so be prepared for negative feedback as a result of problems with your question.

Note that the fact that you have answered it, or plan to self answer it, in no way reduces the quality standards for the question.

> If yes, should I write few words about the context(with link to original question, and this question here on meta), or simply post answer and question?

No, don't include meta-information about the question.  It's noise.  We want to ensure that questions only contain the question and the information needed to answer it, and no more.  Likewise, answers should just contain the information needed to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this blog by Jeff Atwood](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), its fine to answer your own questions, just make sure they're still in the correct Stack Exchange format:

> Bottom line — never hesitate to ask and answer your own question on any Stack Exchange site. Please do! It’s all part of our shared mission to make the internet better.

I don't think you'd need to quote this and the other question though. Questions usually should stand on their own (links can break).

Comment: [Apparently not on meta though.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181225/minimum-rep-needed-to-post-discussion-on-meta-so/181226#comment550654_181226)

Comment: @djechlin I think people were more confused by your self answer because you were disagreeing with yourself, not just because it was a self answer.